# Movie/TV show with crashed Ship that contains a galaxy

Tags: story-identification

When I was a kid I remember seeing a short clip from a movie or TV show probably on the Sci-Fi Channel.  Would have been sometime in the 90's.

I remember there was a large black ship that was crashed in a desert and a man or a couple approached it.  When the man when inside he was standing on a platform and the interior of the ship was a an entire solar system or galaxy.

That's all I remember and the image has been stuck in my head for years.

Any idea what this is from?

It was actually a solar system/Galaxy, there was no screen or projection in evidence.  It appeared as if the protagonist had actually walked into the space around the solar system/Galaxy.

Also I don't believe that he was wearing a space suit.  His clothing would have been more in line with walking in the desert.  White or tan slacks and shirt.  If there was a woman present I have no memory of what she might have been wearing.

Comment: Did it literally contain a solar system or are we talking some kind of holographic display?

Answer (score 4):

This movie is not a perfect match but the description sounds like a scene near the end of the movie [Mission to Mars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0183523/?ref_=nv_sr_1).  Here's an image from the DVD version of the film:

[image: room with solar system display]

The three astronauts had entered a spaceship in the desert just prior to this scene.

Comment: I do remember that scene now that you've mentioned it but this is not it.  I edited my question to mention the fact that it appeared to be an actual solar system/Galaxy not a projection of some kind.